# Mission Control doesn't select app when it's assigned to "All desktops"

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra, spaces, mission-control

If you choose your app to be Assigned to All Desktops, like:

[image: sreenshots]

You won't be able to select it from Mission Control.

Check this video: https://youtu.be/6WHoD_bTn9A

If you set Assign to: None, Mission Control is working great, but the app is locked to the current Space.

How can I fix this? It's really annoying, because I have lots of apps, that I want to be available in every Space.

Hope somebody knows how to fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: I have MacOS 10.11.6 El Capitain and MacOS 10.13.3 High Sierra side by side. In El Capitain it works, in High Sierra it does not. It's a bug IMHO in High Sierra. What about Sierra, anyone?